# MySQL trigger unknow syntax error if statement

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this trigger and it says a syntax error

```
        delimiter //
Create Trigger sal_check
Before Update On emp
For Each Row
Begin
 IF (new.sal > (old.sal * 1.1)) Then 
  signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'The increase to salary is too high';
 End IF;
END 
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Why are you putting a colon `:` before new and old?

Comment: IF (new.sal > (old.sal * 1.1)) Then 
still gives me an error. Im used to oracle that explains the :

Comment: You don't appear to be setting delimiter before or after trigger.

Comment: I did I just didn't copy that here .. I updated the code now

Comment: is it working with you ? I'm using SQL fiddle .., that might cause the error

Comment: Works for me locally but as you say fails in a dbfiddle , removing or replace works in both https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oiy96mjyJVGdFk3yBgvQVJ/0 and or replace is not valid https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: There is no `CREATE OR REPLACE` syntax in MySQL (except in `CREATE VIEW`).

Comment: I've changed it with no luck